# Can specifics on why this question was closed be explained?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I have a question about my Chemistry Stack Exchange post: [Is there an algebraic reason why 1/t is proportional to initial rate?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/144718/is-there-an-algebraic-reason-why-1-t-is-proportional-to-initial-rate)

I posted this and it was almost immediately closed. I can not think of any way to rephrase this question and have searched for hours for an answer. It being too much like a homework question is unavoidable due to the nature of the question, since I figured an explanation of a derivation would actually provide some insight towards the main and original question. May I ask for an explanation of what the problem actually is without it being too much like a homework question?

Comment: It's not so much about rephrasing in this case, I think. My suggestion would be to add more context to your question. What reaction are you considering (is this an iodine clock reaction, or something like that)? What does $t$ refer to? It's a kind of time, but what time period is it supposed to refer to (time taken for the solution to turn dark blue)? What kind of rate laws are you talking about? I can make guesses, but it's better if you explain these things.

Comment: This is a general method for determining the rate of a reaction, specifically rate concentration graphs . There isn't specific reaction in mind, though it can be applied to iodine clock reactions for example. I would of put a specific example if I had one, but was more looking reason (and thus asked for a derivation) on how we can say 1/t ∝ initial rate. I have a idea that it could be explained through integrated rates, as mentioned, but apart from that wasn't sure. I know and understand how this could be applied

Comment: Did you read the close reason provided to you?

Comment: OK, see, I don't 100% agree with the homework close reason,  but I can try and help give pointers as to what might help it get reopened. I think if you had some of this elaboration in your original question it would have been less likely for it to be closed. In particular, please, do explain exactly what $t$ means. In general, $t$ refers to the continuous variable time, which increases as time passes. I suspect you are using it not in this sense, but rather to mean the length of a certain time period.

Comment: If you mean by 'read' I saw you closed it for homework. I'll try take on your suggestion orthocresol, though, thanks - should of done this originally. In general I will try make it more specific, but apart from that I don't how to address the homework complaint.